# Linear transformation between matrices

Tags: matrices

I came across this problem about linear transformation which I don't quite understand. The question asks to suppose that $T: R^3 -> R^2$ is a linear transformation with $T (1, 0, 0) = (4, 5)$, $T (0, 1, 0) = (-1, 1)$, $T (2, 1, -3) = (7, -1)$.

The answer states that we must first write $(0, 0, 1)$ as a linear combination of the vectors (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (2, 1, -3). This gives $T(0, 0, 1) = (0, 4)$, and thus matrix of T is A = $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & -1 & 0 \\
        5 & 1 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

But what I don't understand is I thought that the vectors (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (2, 1, -3) are all linearly independent? So why can't we just take matrix of T to be
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & -1 & 7 \\
        5 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
 ?

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: The same linear map has different matrix representations : you must specify a base in the starting space and another one in the arrival space.

Comment: Wait so do you mean that both these answers are correct? because the question did not specify a base in $R^3$ or $R^2$?

Comment: Your second answer is only correct if you want $(2, 1, -3)$ to be your third-dimension's axis. This means that $(0, 0, 1)$ would be one unit *along the line spanned by* $(2, 1, -3)$. Since you can see that $T(0, 0, 1) \not = (7, -1)$, it should be clear that that's not the basis you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the both bases of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
  :$$\mathcal{B}_{1}=\left(\left(1,0,0\right),\left(0,1,0\right),\left(0,0,1\right)\right)$$
 and$$\mathcal{B}_{2}=\left(\left(1,0,0\right),\left(0,1,0\right),\left(2,1,-3\right)\right).$$
 Let us denote by $\mathcal{B}$
  the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
  :$$\mathcal{B}=\left(\left(1,0\right),\left(0,1\right)\right).$$
 Then$$\textrm{Mat}_{\mathcal{B}_{1},\mathcal{B}}\left(T\right)=\begin{bmatrix}4 & -1 & 0\\
5 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$
 whereas$$\textrm{Mat}_{\mathcal{B}_{2},\mathcal{B}}\left(T\right)=\begin{bmatrix}4 & -1 & 7\\
5 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.$$